# No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

I am using Python version 2.5.4 and install MySQL version 5.0 and Django. Django is working fine with Python, but not MySQL. I am using it in Windows Vista.

Comment: `pip install mysql-python` or `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: I had to install `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` to make it work.

Comment: pip install mysqlclient worked on windows x64 10, You rock Cœur

Comment: For Python3.6 `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` and `pip3 install mysqlclient` worked for me

Comment: My environment is based on windows so I ran `pip install mysqlclient` and it worked.

Answer (score 746):

You need to use one of the following commands. Which one depends on what OS and software you have and use.

1. **easy_install mysql-python** (mix os)
2. **pip install mysql-python** (mix os/ python 2)
3. **pip install mysqlclient** (mix os/ python 3)
4. **apt-get install python-mysqldb** (Linux Ubuntu, ...)
5. **cd /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb && make install clean** (FreeBSD)
6. **yum install MySQL-python** (Linux Fedora, CentOS ...)

For Windows, see this answer: [Install mysql-python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21440230/4646678)

Comment: I had to update my version of setuptools to match my updated version of python on Mac OS before I could get this to work.

Comment: I had several problems with `easy_install`, I think **ActivePython** is very reliable than `easy_install`.

Comment: and how about install on virtualenv with python 3 on it? I used:
 pip install mysql-python
only to get:
 ImportError: No module named ConfigParser

Comment: In Python 3, ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser for PEP 8 compliance. It looks like the package you are installing does not support Python 3.  MySQL-python does not currently support Python 3.

Comment: See this question for some options in Python3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql/25724855#25724855

Comment: I receive this error when using 1 or 2 in `OSX Yosemite`: `EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found`

Comment: easy_install worked for me on macOS High Sierra (v10.13.2) using Python v2.7.14

Comment: FYI - I am on ubuntu 18 and using python3.7. After doing "pip install mysqlclient", I needed to do "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev" for successful installation.

Comment: If you are using Python3 on Ubuntu, it is always recommended to update your repositories before installing a new package so you run "sudo apt-get update" and then you install the package by running "sudo apt-get install python3-mysqldb" and you are good to go.

Comment: I tried `yum install MySQL-python` on my dockerfile (with Python 3.8), but error `No module named 'MySQLdb'` still exists, does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: 3. pip install mysqlclient (mix os/ python 3)

This worked for me on Ubuntu with python3.8.5.

Answer (score 178):

...and remember there is **no MySQLdb for python3.x**

(I know the question is about python2.x but google rates this post quite high)

---

**EDIT:** As stated in the comments, there's a MySQLdb's fork that adds Python 3 support: [github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python](http://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python)

Comment: Urghhgwaarrbl... there goes my hopes of using python3 in my Django app

Comment: Luckily, there is a selection of alternatives, many of which use the same API: [Python 3 and MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql)

Comment: [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) is a fork of MySQLdb that works well with Python 3.

Comment: @JanekOlszak I did not know this - only took about a day of lots of cursing and banging on the keyboard - until reading this and swapping over to 2.7. And guess what, everything works hunky-dory~

Comment: My journey, this -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530768/812919) -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392907/812919). And then, I was finally able to successfully install it.

Comment: Install mysql dev files: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` followed by: `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 98):

if your python version is `3.5`, do a `pip install mysqlclient`, other things didn't work for me

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down-voted, but `mysqlclient` is a fork of the MySQLdb project, and I can confirm this worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: Worked for me on arch linux

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.10, Python 3.5.2+

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04 Python 3.4.3

Comment: Worked on macOS, Python 3.6.0

Comment: On an ec2-instance running Amazon Linux 1 I got this error when running the command `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yozvcc7j/mysqlclient/` and `OSError: mysql_config not found` Although I used `pip-3.6 install mysqlclient` and it sounds like this isn't supported for python 3.6 so maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 Python 3.6.7.

Comment: try "sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev" and then try.

Comment: Worked on Raspbian, Python 3.7

Comment: Worked on python 3.7.9

Comment: Works for me with Django 4.2.3 and Python 3.11 (on Windows 11)

Answer (score 49):

`mysqldb` is a module for Python that doesn't come pre-installed or with Django. You can download `mysqldb` [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python).

Comment: Trying to install MySQL-python-1.2.1

I get the message **ImportError: No module named setuptools**

Trying to install setuptools, I get **zlib not available**

isn't it supposed to be bundled with python ?

Comment: after downloading the module you'll need to edit the site.cfg file with the right path for mysql_config and the run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 41):

For anyone coming to this page when trying to find a solution for `sqlalchemy`, all you need to do is:

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

And adjust your connection string to use PyMySQL, from `mysql://` to `mysql+pymysql://`.

Comment: This also works on M1 Macs. The mysql-python client doesn't work (yet) as of Jan 31, 2021.

Comment: It worked on flask but where can I find the official link to this?

Answer (score 38):

#### Note this is not tested for python 3.x

In CMD

```
pip install wheel
pip install pymysql
```

in settings.py

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

It worked with me

Comment: "pip3 install mysqlclient" solve the problem for python3.6/

Comment: I can't upvote this enough! The only solution that works on Databricks..

Comment: This code pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() save me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. No need to install wheel.

Answer (score 37):

I am at ubuntu (linux) and what worked for me was

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

and then finally

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 34):

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Answer (score 24):

for Windows :

```
pip install mysqlclient pymysql
```

then:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

for python 3 Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-mysqldb
```

Comment: Running just "pip install mysqlclient pymysql" on Windows 10 (Python 3.6.2) resolved my issue.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -y python3-mysqldb worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

and then add this two lines to your Project/Project/**init**.py

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Works on WIN and python 3.3+

Comment: I used your suggestion successfully. Only change was in the import command: import pymysql
There was at type.

Comment: worked for me on windows10, python 3.6, virtual environment

Comment: Love this hack. Although I've managed to get it to work without it yet had to incorporate a whql binary.

Answer (score 13):

Try this.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: How does this apply specifically to virtual environments?

Answer (score 13):

If pip install mysqlclient produces an error and you use Ubuntu, try:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev libmysqlclient-dev && sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: this one worked for me on python 3.6.11 on ubuntu 18.04 on aws

Answer (score 12):

For Python 3.6+

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

does the trick

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3.8

```sh
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install -y python3-mysqldb
```

```
pip3 install pymysql
```

### settings.py

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 7):

I met the same situation under windows, and searched for the solution.

Seeing this post [Install mysql-python (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21440230/2544762).

It points out installing such a pip environment is difficult, needs many other dependencies.

But I finally know that if we use `mysqlclient` with a version down to `1.3.4`, it don't need that requirements any more, so try:

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.3.4
```

Answer (score 7):

I personally recommend using `pymysql` instead of using the genuine MySQL connector, which provides you with a platform independent interface and could be installed through `pip`.

And you could edit the SQLAlchemy URL schema like this:
`mysql+pymysql://username:passwd@host/database`

Answer (score 6):

```
pip install --user mysqlclient
```

above works for me like charm for me.I go the error from sqlalchemy actually.
Environment information :

### Python : 3.6, Ubuntu : 16.04,conda 4.6.8

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on Vista, you may want to check out the [Bitnami Django stack.](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack) It is an all-in-one stack of Apache, Python, MySQL, etc. packaged with [Bitrock](http://bitrock.com) crossplatform installers to make it really easy to get started. It runs on Windows, Mac and Linux. Oh, and is completely free :)

Comment: Then why did you say "If you are running on Vista" if it will work on more than Vista? That's misleading and confusing.

Comment: To Anthony: I just found funny that the top-voted comment provided instructions for Linux, FreeBSD and OSX but not for Vista as specified by the poster

Answer (score 5):

- Go to your project directory with `cd`.
- source/bin/activate (activate your env. if not previously).
- Run the command `easy_install MySQL-python`

Comment: Doesn't work `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to derevo but I think there's another good way for doing this:

1. Download and install [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads#)
2. Open Command Prompt
3. Type `pypm install mysql-python`
4. Read the notes specific to this package.

I think `pypm` is more powerful and reliable than `easy_install`.

Comment: Seems like it requires a paid subscription `Can't install mysql-python-1.2.3: requires Business Edition subscription`

Comment: I don't think so. I remember I've installed that with no problem.

Comment: why do you think pypm is more powerful and reliable than easy_install? any points to support that? any articles / blogposts?

Comment: I think this would be the article / blog post to support that :P I mean, come on, you support such a comment with typically technical arguments, not with someone else who claims the same, but also may not have arguments. However, arguments would be nice ;)

Answer (score 3):

On OSX these commands worked for me

```
brew install mysql-connector-c 
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Python 3+** version

install `mysql-connector` as:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

**Sample Python DB connection code:**

```
import mysql.connector
db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd=""
)
print(db_connection)
```

**Output:**

```
> <mysql.connector.connection.MySQLConnection object at > 0x000002338A4C6B00>
```

This means, database is correctly connected.

Comment: The original question states clearly the error message, which is "No module named MySQLdb". Your solution gives exactly the same error. Thus, your solution is wrong.

Comment: It connects correctly and doesn't give error. Please check again.

Comment: Please read what the original question is and what I wrote. I never mentioned about connection and the original question is not about connection. Is about ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian Buster, the following solution worked for me with python 3.7:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python 3**

Make sure the import order:

```
#BAD
import MySQLdb             # <------ NOT here
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

#GOOD
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb              # <------- HERE!
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried methods above, but still no module named 'MySQLdb', finally, I succeed with

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

my env is unbuntu 14.04

Comment: success for virtualenv/python2.7

Answer (score 2):

If your are using SQLAlchemy and the error is in `/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py`:

```
from ...connectors.mysqldb import (
                        MySQLDBExecutionContext,
                        MySQLDBCompiler,
                        MySQLDBIdentifierPreparer,
                        MySQLDBConnector
                    )
```

so you may have missed mysqldb connector for `SQLAlchemy` and the solution is to re-install sqlalchemy after installing `mysql-python` module.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me on an Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install via docker image.

The following solved it for me:

`apt-get install holland python3-mysqldb`

Answer (score 1):

On my mac running Catalina v10.15.2, I had the following MySQLdb version conflict:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
```

To resolve it, I did the following:

```
pip uninstall MySQL-python
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue with mysql.connector.python version 8.0.24 on mac(if code base is same then the issue should happen in windows as well). [This file](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/lib/mysql/connector/django/base.py) on line 51 imports "from django.db.backends.mysql.base import DatabaseWrapper as MySQLDatabaseWrapper".  The [imported file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py) has following code 14-20(exact code and error that you received is part of code

```
try:
    import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as err:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        'Error loading MySQLdb module.\n'
        'Did you install mysqlclient?'
    ) from err
```

The error is formed here. Not sure why this import keeps coming back in different version of mysql connector but 8.0.23 does not have the import, so I reverted to that version and error was gone... This is incase you wish to continue to work with mysql.connector.python

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 / Python 3.6.5 this works for me:

conda install -y mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Win10 / Python27
this worked for me:

```
easy_install mysql-python
```

all other 'pip install...' failed with dependency errors

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the command apt-get install python-mysqldb, I still encountered the error message below

> mysql_config not found when installing mysqldb python interface

So I first had to run the command below

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

If you use MySQL instead of MariaDB, run the following instead

Then run

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Then now run

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

For `CentOS 8` and `Python3`

`$ sudo dnf install python3-mysqlclient -y`