# AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "rdbms"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I got a simple test to work when deployed, but I get the following error from the development server:

File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 301, in MakeSyncCall
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "rdbms"

Tried sample app given at https://code.google.com/apis/sql/docs/developers_guide_python.html

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the SDK and have you gone through all the steps here? https://code.google.com/apis/sql/docs/before_you_begin.html

Comment: yes, when i try in localhost its not working.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to replicate this, and got the following warning when starting the SDK dev server:

> WARNING  2011-12-27 03:50:59,069 rdbms_mysqldb.py:90] The rdbms API is
>   not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.

What this means is that the Python-MySQL connector library is not installed on my computer.

Here's a write up on stackoverflow for how to install it: [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)

Comment: I already done these steps http://code.google.com/apis/sql/docs/developers_guide_python.html#using_the_python_development_server