# Load CSV data into MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Not sure what I'm missing here but this code runs without any error message, but there's nothing in the table. I'm loading a CSV values in three columns into mysql table

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('students.csv'))
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
          classes, mark )' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
          row)
#close the connection to the database.
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Would appreciate if someone else could have a look.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think you have to do `mydb.commit()` all the insert into.

Something like this

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='',
    db='mydb')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('students.csv'))
for row in csv_data:

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
          classes, mark )' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
          row)
#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Comment: Thanks that works :) But do you know why the values are all in single quotes in the database?

Comment: Try `"insert into testcsv(names, classes, mark) values(%s, %s, %s)", row`

Comment: Danke, if you have any other problems just post a new question :D

Comment: @JakobBowyer how ignore first line from csv.

Comment: For this to work you will need to figure out and create the table with the right schema before loading any CSV.  Also this approach will give you many problems if your data includes numeric columns and/or you have missing (NULL) values in your data. Those problem are automagically handled with the pandas/sqlalchemy approach bellow.

Answer (score 22):

If you do not have the **pandas** and **sqlalchemy** libraries, install them using pip

```
pip install pandas
pip install sqlalchemy
```

We can use **pandas** and **sqlalchemy** to directly insert into the database

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:*Enter password here*@localhost/*Enter Databse name here*') # enter your password and database names here

df = pd.read_csv("Excel_file_name.csv",sep=',',quotechar='\'',encoding='utf8') # Replace Excel_file_name with your excel sheet name
df.to_sql('Table_name',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='append') # Replace Table_name with your sql table name
```

Comment: For me, this produces the error message "No module named MySQLdb". Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246337/7746472 I used pymysql and changed the create engine bit to "mysql+pymysql://..."

Comment: Alternatively, you can solve it by installing `mysqlclient` as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873259/11724813

Answer (score 11):

The above answer seems good. But another way of doing this is adding the auto commit option along with the db connect. This automatically commits every other operations performed in the db, avoiding the use of mentioning `sql.commit()` every time.

```
 mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='mydb',autocommit=true)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  from __future__ import print_function
import csv
import MySQLdb

print("Enter  File  To Be Export")
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="", db="database")
cursor = conn.cursor()
#sql = 'CREATE DATABASE test1'
sql ='''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`; CREATE TABLE test1 (policyID int, statecode varchar(255), county varchar(255))'''
cursor.execute(sql)

with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Code/python/sample.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['policyID'], row['statecode'], row['county'])
        # insert
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="", db="database")
        sql_statement = "INSERT INTO test1(policyID ,statecode,county) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.executemany(sql_statement,[(row['policyID'], row['statecode'], row['county'])])
        conn.escape_string(sql_statement)
        conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 5):

using pymsql if it helps

```
import pymysql
import csv
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","12345678","data" )

cursor = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
next(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO PM(col1,col2) VALUES(%s, %s)',row)

db.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip though, but this was asked over 8 years ago :)

Comment: @HelenNeely agreed then its time to select my answer as correct answer, as open(file) wont work :P

Comment: pretty primitive considering easier options available using pandas.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji No, pretty straightforward, if we don't want to use pandas or/and sqalchemy or sqlite.

Comment: @HelenNeely regardless of when a question was asked, SO serves as a continual reference for people who have the same question as you did 8 years ago. Therefore it makes sense to continually provide new answers as the existing answers become irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a pandas data frame you could do:

## Sending the data

```
csv_data.to_sql=(con=mydb, name='<the name of your table>',
  if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```

to avoid the use of the `for`.

Comment: It seems you quoted from a manual? Add a reference in such cases please, so people can read on in case they're interested (and to give proper reference to the original authors).

Comment: This will not work if index name of your dataframe is not same as column name in database table.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to use MySQL bulk loader by "load data infile" statement. It is the fastest way by far than any way you can come up with in Python. If you have to use Python, you can call statement "load data infile" from Python itself.