# Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mysql

I got the folloiwng error while running my script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysql.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

Tried to install mysql-python as suggested in [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb) but running 
into following error ,can anyone suggest how to overcome this error?

```
C:\Dropbox\scripts>easy_install mysql-python
Searching for mysql-python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/M/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip#md5=654f75b302db6ed8dc5a898c625e030c
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Running MySQL-python-1.2.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\gnakkala\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-kowc5r\MySQL-python-1.2.5\egg-dist-tmp-1gslvq
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: did you try with pip and what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with getting MySQL-python to install properly and work for me. I tried both easy_install and pip, both had issues with vcvarsall.bat. Below is what I did to solve my problem, which I think might be able to lead you in the right direction. I have a Windows 8 Machine, Python 2.7 installed and running my stuff through eclipse.

**Some Background:**

When I did an `easy install` it tries to install `MySQL-python 1.2.5` which failed with an `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. I did an `easy_install` of `pip` and tried the `pip` install which also failed with a similar error. They both reference `vcvarsall.bat` which is something to do with visual studio, since I don't have visual studio on my machine, it left me looking for a different solution, which I share below.

**The Solution:**

1. Reinstall python 2.7.8 from 2.7.8 from https://www.python.org/download this will add any missing registry settings, which is required by the next install.
2. Install 1.2.4 from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4

After I did both of those installs I was able to query my MySQL db through eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1 install wheel

```
pip install wheel
```

2 Download .whl file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Ctrl+F, search mysql . you can find :

```
MySQL-python, a Python database API 2.0 interface for the MySQL database
Mysqlclient is a Python 3 compatible fork of MySQL-python.
MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
Mysqlclient, a fork of the MySQL-python interface for the MySQL database.
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```