# python can't install mysql library

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pip

I want to connect to mysql database from python

I tried to do this: `pip install mysql-python` as this question suggested [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)

but I got this exception

```
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\use
rs\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_User\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec(com
pile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __f
ile__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-kkagjy-re
cord\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed wit
h error code 1 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_User\mysql-python
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\User\pip\pip.log
```

In my python code, I keep getting this error

```
No module named MySQLdb
```

I am using windows 7

Comment: You need a c compiler and a tool chain setup to install this. Do you have a c compiler installed? What operating system are you using? You might want to look at this blog post: http://mysql-python.blogspot.ca/2012/11/is-mysqldb-hard-to-install.html

Comment: @shuttle87 I am using windows 7

Comment: @shuttle87 the blog you suggested stats that I must have `vs2008` and that is impossible now. I have `vs2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself

http://www.codegood.com/archives/129

download that and it is enough

Comment: If you want a more up-to-date repository have a look at [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python).