# Error connecting django to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

When i try to hook up my django project to mysql database i get the following error

manage.py syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django-1.3.3\build\scripts-2.7\collegetree\manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management.sql import custom_sql_for_model, emit_post_sync_signal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
    connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 33, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

While installing some packages, my django automatically started to update to version 1.6 from 1.3.3. I uninstalled 1.6 and reinstalled 1.3.3
Since then i started to face this problem.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

Install Mysql on ubuntu following ways ..

> $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
>   $ sudo apt-get install mysql-client

And later run this command to check mysql running or not

> $sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql

then about this error ..

for the virtualenv or outside the project you need the python mysql connection. Get it using

> apt-get install python-mysqldb

Hope this will help you