# Problem with Ruby Bundle Install, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl, /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto Dradis Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle-install, elementary-os

I'm using Elementary OS and I tried to install [Dradis Framework](https://dradisframework.com/ce/download.html).

I followed all the steps and add some others (for example I installed Ruby 2.5.1p57) and when I ran `./setup` inside `dradis-ce/bin`. Everything looks OK until a error message appears:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I ran `gem install mysql12 -v '0.5.2'` and the mesage console was

```
can't find -ssl- lss-
```

I've already installed `build-essential` and it didn't work. I've installed MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28 and nothing happened.

Comment: Try installing the libssl-dev package. It generally provides -lssl and -lcrypto per this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979525/cannot-find-lssl-cannot-find-lcrypto-when-installing-mysql-python

Comment: Amazing man it worked. Sorry I'm a newbie with this and I spent 3 hours looking for solutions. Thank u some much

Comment: Welcome to SO! An image of an error is not an acceptable substitute for the actual text. SO doesn't block sharing errors as text. See "[I downvoted because an image of your exception isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)", then edit the question and put the text into it, formatted correctly, without "edited" or "updated" tags. By doing so you're helping others solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` options are provided by the libssl-dev package on Ubuntu/Debian and Ubuntu-like systems.

Once you install the libssl-dev package you should be able to install the MySQL2 gem.