# Getting error "no module named mysqldb" even though mysqldb has been installed using pip

Tags: python-2.7

Getting error "no module named mysqldb" even though mysqldb has been installed using pip.

pip install pymysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named MySQLdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)

Comment: Thanks daredevil for the prompt response however this link doesn't works for me. After spending around 4 hrs on this, finally I got the solution myself . Here is the command that I executed and it worked :)...."pip install mysqlclient"

Comment: add your response then to this question :-)

Comment: "pip install mysqlclient"