# Deploying mysql database on a django app to production server

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to deploy a django app on a shared hosting. and i am currently facing issues deploying the app especially the mysql database. I have created the mysql database on the production server. But when trying to run `manage.py collectstatic` command i am getting the below attached error. I am assuming it has something to do with the mysqldb library.

1. I don't know how to go about this. Deploying this mysql database
2. Which ip address should i put on the host part of the db config in the settings.py file. Is it my production server ip address?

Please bear with me i am new to django especially the deployment part. Can't find enough info on the django deployment documentations.

This is the error i am getting on my production server:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home4/techaven/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate question. You have your answer in there >> [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)

As you see in your logs: **Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb**

Comment: so i should also install mysql-python on the production server?

Comment: Yes. wherever you use mysql you need that package for django