# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' In Django

Tags: django, mysql-python, python-3.6

creating my first module in django,

I am using mac Tried steps:

1.installed python 3.6.+ version,

2.cloned git project

3.setup local env,

```
to create a module, 
trying with command 
 env=dev python3 manage.py startapp supriya_module_inflow;
```

getting error in console :

```
Environment Selected :dev
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 35, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)......
...
 raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Answer (score 9):

MySQLdb does not support Python 3. You'll want to pick one of the other [MySQL drivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#id8).

> At the time of writing, the latest release of MySQLdb (1.2.5) doesn’t support Python 3. In order to use MySQLdb under Python 3, you’ll have to install `mysqlclient` instead.

Here is [How to install **mysqlclient** in Python using **pip**](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) so as to be able to **import MySQLdb** in **Django 3.1** when running **Python 3.8.5**..

Comment: I am not getting anything in this link, do you have any short command for the same ?

Comment: "MySQLdb is the only [driver] not supporting Python 3 currently." - You'll need to install another one of the listed drivers if you want to work with Python 3. In short, `pip install mysqlclient` in your virtualenv should work.

Comment: You'll need to supply some more information if you'd like more detailed help, but your issue is most likely rooted around what it means for a Python package to be installed system-wide versus in a virtuanenv (and what it means to activate a virtualenv). I'd recommend you do some reading there, and the solution to your current problems should become obvious!

Comment: followed your steps after upgrading pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` worked :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there is no module named MySQLdb. It means, Python needs a module to interface with MySQL database and that modules does not seems to be present in the system. All you need to do is, just install MySQL-Python module and the script should work without any problem.

**Using Python Pip**

## pip install MySQL-python

```
Collecting MySQL-python
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
 Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
Successfully installed MySQL-python-1.2.5
```

**On Ubuntu based systems**

```
# apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

**On RHEL/CentOS based systems:**

```
# yum install MySQL-python
```

**Using easy_install**

```
# easy_install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a virtual environment then

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

You can also check this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb).

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages getting this

Comment: are you realy work in env now? your env created with `python3`, but the error message is python2. I think you aren't..

Comment: you can activate it with command (if linux): `$ source dev/bin/activate`. and here you should install it `(dev) $ pip install MySQL-python`. the `dev` mean is the environtment that you created before.

Answer (score 0):

** Building wheel for MySQL-python (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:**

can't able to install MySQL-python and getting the above error .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30254220)