# "ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'MySQLdb'",)" when deploying a OpenLiteSpeed django solution on GCP

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-cloud-platform

I'm testing Google Cloud Platform, where I've deployed a OpenLiteSpeed Django solution with a Ubuntu VM on Google Compute Engine. When it's deployed, everything works like a charm, and I'm able to reach the "Hello, world" starting page.

When I try to add my own simple script by changing the `views.py` file in `/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/app` to:

```
import MySQLdb
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def getFromDB():
    data = []
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="ip",
                      user="user",
                      passwd="pw",
                      db="db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
    for student in students:
        data.append(student)
    return data


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(getFromDB)
```

and access the IP again I'm met with the following traceback and error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://ip/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 544, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/demo/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/usr/local/lsws/Example/html/demo/app/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

[image]

I've tried running `./pip3 install mysqlclient` in the `/usr/bin` directory, along with `sudo apt install python3-dev` and `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev` with no luck. Can anyone help with this? I'm new working with apps.

**UPDATE:**
So, by trying out a bunch of different stuff, I finally fixed the problem by cd'ing into `/usr/bin` and executing `sudo -H ./pip3 install mysqlclient`. I'm not entirely sure why it didn't give me any permission error, when just executing `./pip3 install mysqlclient` - however now the issue is resolved.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490797/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-mysqldb-in-django  you should switch to aniother driver because this is not supported anymore

Comment: @nbk when I run python3 directly through SSH in the VM I can `import MySQLdb` with no issues.

Comment: iI use import mysql.connector  that works without a problem, yur umport doesn't work with me and other

Comment: @nbk That's weird... I'll try switching connector.

Comment: error fixed by running `sudo -H ./pip3 install mysqlclient` instead of `./pip3 install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

Is MySQLdb installed? Do you see it when you enter pip3 list?

I've seen in the docs that the proposal is to import MySQLdb like this.

```
from MySQLdb import _mysql
```

https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html

Comment: I've tried changing the import in the script, with no luck.

Comment: ...and yes, I have installed MySQLdb