# can't connect django 1.10 to mysql 5.7, mysqlclient installed but still get ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: mysql, django

I created a virtual environment with python 3.5 then used pip to install `mysqlclient`. When I activate the venv and go into the python shell I can type `import MySQLdb` and then proceed to query my db **without** any trouble. However, in django 1.10.5 when I use this virtual environment I get `ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'` as soon as I start the local/dev server. For what it's worth, I also tried this process outside of a virtual environment but no success.

I'm on windows and Pycharm and created the venv in CMD with administrator privileges. I know there are similar questions on SO but nothing is on point here. Thanks for whatever help you can give!

My settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db_name',
        'USER': 'my_user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a MySQL module for Python.

Run this:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

Make sure you install this under your virtualenv.

Comment: Perhaps not surprisingly I get an error when I try to install this with pip...looking past that for a moment, do I need this module and mysqlclient? Thanks for the help...

Comment: Generally, you need either `PyMySQL` or `mysql-python` modules. These should include all you will need to connect to MySQL database using Django.