# Cannot install MySQLdb (mysql-python) on CentOS

Tags: python, centos, mysql-python

I am using ActivePython version 2.7.13 and install MySQLdb. However the following error occurs when I use '**pip install mysql-python**'.

`Command "/opt/ActivePython-2.7/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-xRB3M9/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-qnksTb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-xRB3M9/mysql-python/`

I have tried a lot approaches, like [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed! Firstly, **yum install mysql-devel**. Then  **pip install mysql-python**.     This problem confused me for a long time, it's pleasure to fix it.

Comment: Maybe this question is for Super User https://superuser.com/