# Django 2.0 - Python3.6 - CentOS 7 - MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, centos7

i try to install my website on a webserver which is in CentOS 7 with Django 2.0.6 and Python 3.6.

I installed : `mysql-connector = 2.1.6`,
              `mysql-connector-python = 8.0.11`,
              `MySQL-python = 1.2.5`,
              `mysqlclient = 1.3.12`,
              `PyMySQL = 0.8.1`

And when i run this command :

```
python3.6 manage.py migrate
```

I have this error :

```
  File "MYPYTHONPATH/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 36, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("mysqlclient 1.3.3 or newer is required; you have %s" % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.3 or newer is required; you have 1.2.5
```

But in the base.py file :

```
try:
   import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as err:
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
    'Error loading MySQLdb module.\n'
    'Did you install mysqlclient?'
) from err

from MySQLdb.constants import CLIENT, FIELD_TYPE                # isort:skip
from MySQLdb.converters import conversions                      # isort:skip

# Some of these import MySQLdb, so import them after checking if it's installed.
from .client import DatabaseClient                          # isort:skip
from .creation import DatabaseCreation                      # isort:skip
from .features import DatabaseFeatures                      # isort:skip
from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip
from .operations import DatabaseOperations                  # isort:skip
from .schema import DatabaseSchemaEditor                    # isort:skip
from .validation import DatabaseValidation                  # isort:skip

version = Database.version_info
if version < (1, 3, 3):
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("mysqlclient 1.3.3 or newer is required; you have %s" % Database.__version__)
```

I dont understand what can i do for resolving this kind of problem !
I hope someone can help me on =)

Comment: Well the error already says it: you have to upgrade `mysqlclient`. So `pip install --upgrade mysqlclient-python`.

Comment: Why have you installed all these different MySQL libraries? You only need one, probably mysqlclient. Uninstall the others.

Comment: Furthermore are you sure that you installed this in a (possible) virtual environment?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysqlclient-python`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I listed all mysql librairie of my virtualenv python3.6

Comment: @DalinDad: yes, but do you use the virtual env when you run `manage.py`? Otherwise it will fallback to your global env.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have this error know `python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    from MySQLdb.constants import CLIENT, FIELD_TYPE                # isort:skip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb.constants'`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. `(venv-site_cnr-python3.6) [X@X]$ which python3.6` i have `/PATHTOMYENV/venv-site_cnr-python3.6/bin/python3.6`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved it with the answer of this thread.

[No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

and then add this two lines to your Project/Project/init.py

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Works on WIN and python 3.3+