# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' " on the code "import MySQLdb" on Windows 10

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I tried to write a python code that import data from excel to MySQL database. When I tried to run it, there was an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' " on the code "import MySQLdb". I searched on-line intensively but I could not solve the problem. "MySQL" folder contains  Connector C++ 8.0, Connector ODBC 8.0, MySQL Connector Python 8.0 for Python 3.7, MySQL Router 8.0, MySQL Server 8.0, MySQL Shell 8.0, MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. It seems to me that I have everything needed. Please, give me some advice. It is on Windows 10. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add the Python code that you tried to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)