# No module named 'MySQLdb' after installing mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, module

I am using PyCharm and I'm trying to make a simple script that connects to a database.

In the PyCharm terminal, both mysqlclient installations from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) seem to fail.

```
(venv) C:\Users\erics\CS261>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

(venv) C:\Users\erics\CS261>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

In Windows's terminal, they are succesfully installed:

```
C:\Users\erics>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\erics\mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.6
```

Even though it is "succesfully installed", my script does not seem to run...

```
C:\Users\erics\CS261\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/erics/CS261/venv/Scripts/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/erics/CS261/venv/Scripts/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi Eric! What version of Python are you using? Could you try some of the solutions given on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)?

Comment: hello @Ivanhercaz, I am using Python 3.8, I tried ```pip install mysqlclient```, but with no success

Comment: ```MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```