# unable to install mysql-python for python 2.7.18 on windows 10

Tags: python, mysql-python

When I compiled a python script, this error shows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitcrack.py", line 41, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I tried to install mysql-python. I need to use only Python 2.7.18 on windows 10.

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'E:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-wheel-v322tt'
       cwd: c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-auuahc\mysql-python\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IE:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\include -IE:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
    Running setup.py install for mysql-python ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'E:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-t45lxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'E:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\include\site\python2.7\mysql-python'
         cwd: c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-auuahc\mysql-python\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IE:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\include -IE:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'E:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-auuahc\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'c:\users\pc\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-t45lxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'E:\Work\ecdsa-private-key-recovery\env\include\site\python2.7\mysql-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried in many ways. But it's not solved. Already installed MS VS Dev Tools. One questions: Do I have to run MySQL server to install this package? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Comment: @Jonas I tried but not worked. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use sqlalchemy (you could save the whole query which will of course be more complicated than the one in the example):

```
# Import sqlalchemy's create_engine() function
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

# Create the database engine
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@dsn")

# Create a SQL query to load the entire table
query = """
SELECT * 
  FROM XXX;
"""

# Load with the SQL query
load = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Please let me know if any issues.