# How to solve 'no module named mysqldb'?

Tags: python, module, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am new to python. I am following a tutorial series tk make a website using flask. But when i fill up the contact form and then click on send i get this error

> ```
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
> ```

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 1020, in __call__
return self.registry[key]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\acer\PycharmProjects\webdev.flask\first.1.py", line 46, in contact
db.session.add(entry)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 163, in do
return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 1022, in __call__
return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3286, in __call__
return self.class_(**local_kw)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 138, in __init__
bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 943, in engine
return self.get_engine()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 962, in get_engine
return connector.get_engine()
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 556, in get_engine
self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 972, in create_engine
return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 87, in create
dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
File "C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I tried to install mysqlient but it also gives ' cant build the wheel ' error.
I am using python 3.8

How to solve this issue?

Comment: just follow this link -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use pycharm then file - > settings -> interpreter - > + (right). there you install wheel and mysql client (not always the latest version works)
2. if manually I assume that you are using a virtual environment, then you need to activate it and it already has "pip install wheel" also mysqlclient