# sqlalchemy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy to use pandas.dataframe.to_sql() but when I try to create an engine I get the mentioned error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I see that many people have issues with this from a multitude of packages but I have not found a solution that works, I'm working on a mac OS 10.13.6 and python 3.9.6.
I tried installing a few packages and they had no effect, I cannot install mysqlclient, is this the only solution? It all seems a bit complicated to just use the very basic functions of sqlalchemy.

Comment: Can you, please, provide more code samples?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454854/no-module-named-mysqldb)

Comment: You can use a different package, for example pymysql.  You will need to configure the engine URL accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I think MySQLdb is no longer supported for Python3.x

Instead you can use PyMySQL like this: https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/

To configure your engine, use:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@host:port/database')
```

Comment: thank you! i didn't know that i then needed to specify the package i want to use instead in the engine-creation :)